# Python Remove List of Strings from List of Strings

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to remove several strings from a list of URLs. I have more than 300k URLs, and I'm trying to find which are variations of the original. Here's a toy example that I've been working with.

```
URLs = ['example.com/page.html',
        'www.example.com/in/page.html',
        'example.com/ca/fr/page.html',
        'm.example.com/de/page.html',
        'example.com/fr/page.html']

locs = ['/in', '/ca', '/de', '/fr', 'm.', 'www.']
```

What I'd like to end up with is a list of the pages without the language or locations:

```
desired_output = ['example.com/page.html',
                  'example.com/page.html',
                  'example.com/page.html',
                  'example.com/page.html',
                  'example.com/page.html']
```

I've tried list comprehension and nested for loops, nothing has worked yet. Can anyone help?

```
# doesn't remove anything
for item in URLs:
    for string in locs:
        re.sub(string, '', item)

# doesn't remove anything
for item in URLs:
    for string in locs:
        item.strip(string)

# only removes the last string in locs
clean = []
for item in URLs:
    for string in locs:
        new = item.replace(string, '')
    clean.append(new)
```

Comment: `re.sub` and `item.strip` return the modified string. You need to capture the return value to keep it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to assign the result of `replace` to `item` again:

```
clean = []
for item in URLs:
    for loc in locs:
        item = item.replace(loc, '')
    clean.append(item)
```

or in short:

```
clean = [
    reduce(lambda item,loc: item.replace(loc,''), [item]+locs)
    for item in URLs
]
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem you have is that you don't save the return value.

```
urls = ['example.com/page.html',
        'www.example.com/in/page.html',
        'example.com/ca/fr/page.html',
        'm.example.com/de/page.html',
        'example.com/fr/page.html']

locs = ['/in', '/ca', '/de', '/fr', 'm.', 'www.']

stripped = list(urls) ## create a new copy, not necessary

for loc in locs:
    stripped = [url.replace(loc, '') for url in stripped]
```

After this, `stripped` is equal to

```
['example.com/page.html',
 'example.com/page.html',
 'example.com/page.html',
 'example.com/page.html',
 'example.com/page.html']
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, without creating a new list, you can do

```
for loc in locs:
    urls = [url.replace(loc, '') for url in urls]
```

After this, `urls` is equal to

```
['example.com/page.html',
 'example.com/page.html',
 'example.com/page.html',
 'example.com/page.html',
 'example.com/page.html']
```

Comment: creating a new list is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Well, better safe than sorry. It's just to emphasize the fact that the original is going to be changed. But you're right, you can definitely leave that out.

Comment: better you know, what the program does. The lists are never changed. You always create a new list.

Comment: Yes but you lose the reference, so it'll get collected.

Comment: since there is still a reference to `urls`, the list isn't collected

Answer (score 2):

You could first abstract the removing part into a function and then use a list comprehension:

```
def remove(target, strings):
    for s in strings:
        target = target.replace(s,'')
    return target

URLs = ['example.com/page.html',
        'www.example.com/in/page.html',
        'example.com/ca/fr/page.html',
        'm.example.com/de/page.html',
        'example.com/fr/page.html']

locs = ['/in', '/ca', '/de', '/fr', 'm.', 'www.']
```

Used like:

```
URLs = [remove(url,locs) for url in URLs]

for url in URLs: print(url)
```

output:

```
example.com/page.html
example.com/page.html
example.com/page.html
example.com/page.html
example.com/page.html
```